# How to right button drag with Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi

I implemented the IDropTarget interface and the drag & drop (file from explorer) works well.

When I drag & drop a file with right mouse button, the context menu does not popup.

So I think it's my responsibility to show the context menu,

But in IDropTarget::Drop method, (grfKeyState & MK_RBUTTON) is always 0.

How can I know if the drag mouse button was right?

And is there a special method to show menu and receive the selection after the drop?

(I prefer the Win32 API way, I don't use MFC.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess (`grfKeyState & MK_RBUTTON`) is always 0 because when the `Drop()` method is called, the mouse button is already released (you've just made the drop) - so naturally the keyboard/mouse state flags would indicate that it is indeed released.

What you can (and *should*, according to the documentation) do, is to decide ahead the course of action you take on Drop() when you're handling `DropEnter()`. I haven't tried it myself, but I'm quite sure that the **MK_RBUTTON** flag should be set there. You can check that flag when your drop target's `DropEnter()` method is being called, save it and then open the context menu yourself when `Drop()` is called. This is not the cleanest solution, but I don't know if there's a way to make Windows show a context menu for you.